# Manually and auto assigning constructor parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The following code is what I always use to defined a constructor in `TypeScript` so far.

```
export class DashboardComponent {
    private heroService: HeroService;
    constructor(heroService: HeroService){
        this.heroService = heroService
    }
}
```

But recently when I check the `Angular 2` [document](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html), I saw the syntax is shorter and look like

```
export class DashboardComponent {
    constructor(private heroService: HeroService){}
}
```

And the compiled JavaScript is the same

```
var DashboardComponent = (function () {
    function DashboardComponent(heroService) {
        this.heroService = heroService;
    }
    return DashboardComponent;
}());
```

Because on the `TypeScript` [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) only show the first type so I just want to make sure that two is the same and I am doing correctly with both of those types.

Appreciate If someone can help me to confirm it?

Comment: Don't do it manually: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the two ways of writing it are effectively the same. You can see the second one being used with `public` on the official language specification [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1.6) on GitHub.

So,

```
class BankAccount {  
    constructor(public balance: number) {}  
}
```

is the same as

```
class BankAccount {
    public balance: number
    constructor(balance: number) {
        this.balance = balance;  
    }  
}
```

Also, a note on the generated JavaScript code : Using `private` or `public` won't change the output. Because in pure JavaScript, there's no such thing as a "private" member : You can't prevent an access to a member of your object.
The only effect `public` and `private` have is telling TypeScript what should and what shouldn't be accessed by other code.

Comment: I also found a good resource regarding TypeScript shortcut.
https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#creating-a-class-for-the-data